# Undefined reference when compiling OpenSSL

Tags: gcc, makefile, openssl

I'm not sure what to do here, I ran `make` and got this:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/openssl-1.0.1/test'
( :; LIBDEPS="${LIBDEPS:--L.. -lssl -L.. -lcrypto  -ldl}"; LDCMD="${LDCMD:-gcc}"; LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:--DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -fno-exceptions -Wa,--noexecstack -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM}"; LIBPATH=`for x in $LIBDEPS; do echo $x; done | sed -e 's/^ *-L//;t' -e d | uniq`; LIBPATH=`echo $LIBPATH | sed -e 's/ /:/g'`; LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LDCMD} ${LDFLAGS} -o ${APPNAME:=rc4test} rc4test.o ${LIBDEPS} )
rc4test.o: In function `main':
rc4test.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/openssl-1.0.1/test'
make[1]: *** [rc4test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/openssl-1.0.1/test'
make: *** [build_tests] Error 1
```

I think this is a gcc thing, but I am not sure how to approach this. Should I be compiling this manually?

Comment: What is your operating system and what arguments did you pass to `./config`?

Comment: I tried a few things `-fPIC`, `-fno-exceptions` and nothing in the ./config and Debian Squeeze I know I can use `apt-get`, but I would rather compile my own.

Comment: No warranties, but you could try editing `crypto/cryptlib.c`, look for the line that contains `#if !defined(OPENSSL_CPUID_SETUP) && !defined(OPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ)` and remove remove the `&& !defined(OPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ)` piece. You are in good company, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium-source-browsing/source/browse/patches/empty_OPENSSL_cpuid_setup.patch?repo=third-party--openssl).

Comment: "undefined reference" is a LINKER 'thing'.  You've specified a function that the linker can't find in the given set of libraries.  Check your spelling, check your `-lxxx` type library options. (And were did you get that command line?!?  No, no.. I don't want to know)

Comment: @Reinier Nope, doesn't work! Thanks though! Lornix, I'll try that.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem, and was able to solve it by passing adding `-DOPENSSL_PIC` to the config call:

```
./config -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC
```